# Adicionar sufixo à primeira linha de arquivo de texto usando BAT

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Boas pessoal!

Estou editando uns mods do jogo F1C, que usa arquivos de texto para armazenar os dados de IA dos pilotos.

Na primeira linha de cada arquivo vêm o nome do piloto:

```
Michael Schumacher
```

... e eu gostaria de adicionar um sufixo no final do nome, mais ou menos isso:

```
Michael SchumacherRH
```

É possível fazer isso usando apenas o CMD/.bat (se possível usando um FOR pra fazer isso de uma vez pra todos os arquivos da pasta)?

PS.: Segundo o Notepad++ os arquivos estão sob a codificação UTF-8 (sem BOM)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode começar fazendo o seguinte. O comando FOR do cmd pode ser usado para isso. Você pode usar a opção /F. Essa opção lê cada linha do arquivo. Envie a saída para outro arquivo com o sufixo já adicionado. Exemplo:

Conteúdo do arquivo Teste.txt:

> NOME1
>
> NOME2
>
> NOME3
>
> NOME4

Quero acrescentar a letra RH no final de cada linha. Para isso vou usar o seguinte:

```
FOR /F "eol=M" %i IN (test.txt) DO ECHO %iRH >> Teste-com-sufixo.txt
```

Agora o arquivo **Teste-com-sufixo.txt** ficará assim:

> NOME1RH
>
> NOME2RH
>
> NOME3RH
>
> NOME4RH

Isso já é um começo.